# How to solve Error importing FontAwesome in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've installed `FontAwesome` package from this flutter package repo.
https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

When I paste this line I got an error , `import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';`

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.
```

I tried `flutter pub get` , restarted vsCode many times .

pubspec.yaml :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: <latest_version>
  http: any
```

Comment: Change the `<latest_version>` to `any` or `^9.2.0`

Comment: @esentis : yes I've done that , nothing changed still same error.

Comment: After the changes type `flutter pub get` to get the dependencies.

Comment: I've checked my packages directory , and FontAwesome is there .

Comment: @esentis : Nothing changed ..

Answer (score 0):

For some reason , that I don't know , changing the project directory solved the problem.